# Failure 1 (near "NULLenergy_rates": syntax error) on 0x2d7a30

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite

I'm creating an Database for my Application that I am creating however whenever I run my application and try to enter some information into my database nothing happens and an error message is displayed in the LogCat.
The full error message is:

"04-09 17:22:18.208: E/Database(484): Failure 1 (near "NULLenergy_rates": syntax error) on 0x2d7a30 when preparing 'CREATE TABLE ApplianceDetails (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, appliance_name TEXT NOT NULL, appliance_wattage TEXT NOT NULLenergy_rates TEXT NOT NULL);'.

It is associated with this code:

```
public class Database {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "appliance_name";
public static final String KEY_WATTAGE = "appliance_wattage";
public static final String KEY_ENERGY = "energy_rates";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TheApplianceKeeperdb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "ApplianceDetails";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_WATTAGE + " TEXT NOT NULL" +
                KEY_ENERGY + " TEXT NOT NULL);"                                 
        );      
    }
```

any help on how I can fix this error would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Print out the complete query string (using `System.out.println`), and you will spot the error immediately.

Comment: Missing a space before KEY_ENERGY, just as the error msg implies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a comma and space changing

`KEY_WATTAGE + " TEXT NOT NULL" +` to
`KEY_WATTAGE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +`

Comment: I feel a bit silly that it was something to obvious, but thanks a lot! It is working now!

Comment: No trouble... only if you would mark this as the correct answer. :)